# Can't start httpd 2.4.9 with self-signed SSL certificate

Tags: httpd, openssl, apache-2.4, mod-ssl

I cannot start the httpd 2.4.9 (tried 2.4.x too) on CentOS 6.5 with the simplest SSL config possible. The openssl version installed on the machine is `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` (I've upgraded it using 'yum update' to the latest patched version as well)

I have compiled and installed the httpd 2.4.9 using the following commands:

```
./configure --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/ --enable-proxy=shared --enable-proxy_wstunnel=shared --with-apr=apr-1.5.1/ --with-apr-util=apr-util-1.5.3/
make
make install
```

Now I'm generating the default self-signed certificate as described in the CentOS HowTo:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
cp server.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf
cp server.key /usr/local/apache2/conf
cp server.csr /usr/local/apache2/conf
```

Here is my httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
Listen 443
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
    ServerName 192.168.9.128
    ServerAdmin mymail@mail.com
    ErrorLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/error_log"
    TransferLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

when I start httpd using `bin/apachectl -k start` I get following errors in the `error_log`:

```
Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.995654 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.995726 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] AH01914: Configuring server 192.168.9.128:443 for SSL protocol
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.995863 2014] [ssl:debug] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] ssl_engine_init.c(312): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996111 2014] [ssl:debug] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] ssl_util_ssl.c(343): AH02412: [192.168.9.128:443] Cert matches for name '192.168.9.128' [subject: CN=192.168.9.128,OU=XXX,O=XXXX,L=XXXX,ST=NRW,C=DE / issuer: CN=192.168.9.128,OU=XXX,O=XXXX,L=XXXX,ST=NRW,C=DE / serial: AF04AF31799B7695 / notbefore: Jun  3 22:26:45 2014 GMT / notafter: Jun  3 22:26:45 2015 GMT]
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996122 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] AH02568: Certificate and private key 192.168.9.128:443:0 configured from /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt and /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996209 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] AH01914: Configuring server 192.168.9.128:443 for SSL protocol
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996280 2014] [ssl:debug] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] ssl_engine_init.c(312): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996295 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for 192.168.9.128:443
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996303 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996308 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996318 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Wed Jun 04 00:29:27.996321 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24021:tid 139640404293376] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

I then try to generate missing DH PARAMETERS and EC PARAMETERS:

```
openssl dhparam -outform PEM -out dhparam.pem 2048
openssl ecparam -out ec_param.pem -name prime256v1
cat dhparam.pem ec_param.pem >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt
```

And it mitigates the error but the next comes out:

```
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.021438 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.021487 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] AH01914: Configuring server 192.168.9.128:443 for SSL protocol
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.021874 2014] [ssl:debug] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] ssl_engine_init.c(312): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022050 2014] [ssl:debug] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] ssl_util_ssl.c(343): AH02412: [192.168.9.128:443] Cert matches for name '192.168.9.128' [subject: CN=192.168.9.128,OU=XXX,O=XXXX,L=XXXX,ST=NRW,C=DE / issuer: CN=192.168.9.128,OU=XXX,O=XXXX,L=XXXX,ST=NRW,C=DE / serial: AF04AF31799B7695 / notbefore: Jun  3 22:26:45 2014 GMT / notafter: Jun  3 22:26:45 2015 GMT]
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022066 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] AH02568: Certificate and private key 192.168.9.128:443:0 configured from /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt and /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022285 2014] [ssl:debug] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] ssl_engine_init.c(1016): AH02540: Custom DH parameters (2048 bits) for 192.168.9.128:443 loaded from /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022389 2014] [ssl:debug] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] ssl_engine_init.c(1030): AH02541: ECDH curve prime256v1 for 192.168.9.128:443 specified in /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022397 2014] [ssl:info] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] AH01914: Configuring server 192.168.9.128:443 for SSL protocol
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022464 2014] [ssl:debug] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] ssl_engine_init.c(312): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022478 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for 192.168.9.128:443
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022488 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Wed Jun 04 00:34:05.022491 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24089:tid 140719371077376] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

AH00016: Configuration Failed

I have tried to generate the simple certificate/key pair exactly as described in the [httpd docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_faq.html#selfcert) Unfortunately, I still get exact same errors as above.

I've seen a bug report with the similar issue:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56410
But the openssl version I have is reported as working there. I've also tried to apply the patch from the report as well as build the latest 2.4.x branch with no success, I get the same errors as above.

I have also tried to create a short chain of certificates and set the root CA certificate using SSLCertificateChainFile directive. That didn't help either, I get exact same errors as above.

I'm not interested in setting up hardened security, etc. The only thing I need is to start httpd with the simplest SSL config possible to continue testing proxy config for the mod_proxy_wstunnel

Had anybody encountered and solved this issue?

Is my sequence for creating a self-signed certificate incorrect?

I'd appreciate any help very much!

PS: Updated the initial http-ssl.conf to reflect the correct state as I was testing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be with the certificate you've generated. Looks like you've forgotten/skipped some steps.
I think you've specified some passphrase for the certificate and apache is unable to locate that. Passphrase could be specified through SSLPassPhraseDialog which is missing in your configuration file.

Alternately, you could avoid this passphrase by stripping it from the certificate while generating certificate.
I had succesfully generated a self signed certificate by following steps at http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

I would suggest to regenerate a new certificate using the instructions mentioned at the above link and test it again....

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
The SSLPassPhraseDialog is present in my config (see the original message).
I've followed the steps in your article and still get the same errors as above. I don't think that your steps are much different than those specified on CentOs HowTo and httpd docs pages (except that there is a shorter way to generate a passwordless certificate and a key: `openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key -days 365`.
I've also tried to use the password protected key. The httpd asks for it on startup as expected and fails with the same error afterwards :(

Answer (score 0):

Your initial command that creates the Certificate Authority may not be correct. I would try rebuilding the CA using these commands, taken from the Arch Linux Wiki:

```
# openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out server.key
# chmod 600 server.key
# openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
# openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thank you for the advise!
Unfortunately, 'm seeing exactly same errors (missing DH/EC parameters first, "no certificate assigned" after parameters are appended to the server.crt)

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, I've noticed that you are using a vulnerable OpenSSL version (1.0.1e-fips). This version is affected by the famous heartbleed bug. 
Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed for more details.

You could try upgrading you OpenSSL to the appropriate latest release that addresses this issue.

Comment: I think I've migigated that by using the 'yum update'.
The "real" openssl version on my system is now openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64 which is a patched version against heart-bleed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my problem was incorrectly built httpd with the "wrong" openssl.
Initially, I've downloaded the the openssl 1.0.1g sources, built and installed them and referenced installed version when configuring httpd:

```
cd ../openssl-1.0.1g
./config -fPIC no-gost no-shared no-zlib 
make depend
make
make install 

cd ../httpd-2.4.9
./configure --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/ --with-apr=apr-1.5.1/ --with-apr-util=apr-util-1.5.3/
make
make install
```

Instead, I've installed openssl-devel package using yum and used default openssl location:

```
yum install openssl-devel
cd ../httpd-2.4.9
./configure --enable-ssl --with-apr=apr-1.5.1/ --with-apr-util=apr-util-1.5.3/
make
make install
```

The server started right after the installation with the simple certificate generated in the /usr/local/apache2/conf folder using the following command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key
```

Answer (score 0):

4 years after the original poster solved his problem, I happened upon this page between having a similar problem and finding the solution. Quite different, but posted for those that come here after researching similar error messages. My configuration is much like yours, perfectly valid for httpd-2.2, but mysteriously not working for httpd-2.4 where things just need to be done a little differently. After pulling out many hairs, this eventually worked for me. First the clue: You can't rely on just your VirtualHost definition anymore. You *must* reference a valid certificate/key pair from conf.d/ssl.conf like so (locations are for my Fedora system):

> SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
>
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.pem

Mine is a self-signed cert, carried over from httpd-2.2/openssl-1.0.2h. The cert is in ascii PEM format. The key was converted to an RSA clear copy, so no password is required when httpd starts. (carefully evaluate your environment before you do that). It doesn't matter much what the cert is made for it seems, because it is still the certs, defined in the VirtualHost section that will be presented to the clients. For me those certs (carried over from httpd-2.2) are in PEM short form, while the respective keys, again are in RSA clear copy form. Of course you must have mod_ssl.so loaded, but if you had things working in httpd-2.2 then you already did that.